# How to use a subset of all possible vector combinations in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a data set of species found at different sites. I use those found at more than three sites as the focus to calculate some indices of biodiversity.

In my current code I randomly select three sites with the selected species present.

```
subset(sites, Site %in% sample(unique(Site), 3))
```

But I would like to calculate the indices for ALL possible combinations where the species is found.

I can extract all of the combinations with something like this:

```
x <- list()
for( i in bat_names){
  x[i] <-  filter(bats_data,Gen_sp == i) %>% group_map(~combn(unique(.$Site),3))
}
x
```

But I'm unsure of how to integrate it with the rest of the code so that I cycle through these combinations.

For each species I'd get a gamma value for each combination whereas now I only get one per species.

Here's the script:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(5)

# extract the common species
bats3 <-
  bats_data %>% count(Gen_sp) %>% filter(n > 3)

# get the species names
bat_names <- unique(bats3$Gen_sp)

# create an empty list with correct names
theta.output.bats.3 <- list()

# function for gamma diversity
for (i in 1:length(bat_names)) {
  selTaxon <- bats3[bats3$Gen_sp == bat_names[i], ] 
  sites <- bats_data %>% filter(Gen_sp %in% selTaxon$Gen_sp) %>% distinct(Site) %>% 
    left_join(bats_data) %>% select(Site, Gen_sp, Numbers, presence)
  sites1 <- subset(sites, Site %in% sample(unique(Site), 3))  # this is the relevant line 
  gamma <- nrow(distinct(sites1, Gen_sp)) 
  theta.output.bats.3$Species[i] <- paste(bat_names[i]) 
  theta.output.bats.3$gamma[i] <- gamma
}

theta.output.bats.3
```

Here's a sample from the data set so the code runs:

```
bats_data <- structure(list(Site = c("MOZ_Codzo", "KEN_Sokoke1", "NGA_Gotel", 
                        "ZAF_Pafuri", "COD_Kitwit", "GIN_Diecke", "MWI_Mulanje2", "NER_W", 
                        "GAB_Maboumine", "COD_Kitwit", "SWZ_Lubombo", "GIN_Ziama2", "ZAF_Kruger1", 
                        "KEN_Kakamega", "NGA_Delta", "CMR_Dja", "ZAF_Pafuri", "KEN_Kakamega", 
                        "ZAF_Wakefield", "SWZ_Lubombo", "BDI_Bururi", "ZAF_Soutpansberg", 
                        "ZAF_Kruger2", "GIN_Simandou2", "GIN_Simandou1", "CMR_Maroua", 
                        "CMR_Cameroon2", "KEN_Kakamega", "SWZ_IYSIS", "CMR_Cameroon4", 
                        "ZWE_Sengwa", "TZA_Coastal2", "GIN_Ziama1", "ZAF_Kruger3", "SLE_Seli", 
                        "CIV_Tai", "GIN_Nimba1", "GIN_Simandou1", "MWI_Zomba1", "NER_W", 
                        "GIN_Ziama1", "ZAF_Soutpansberg", "LBR_Nimba3", "CIV_Tai", "TZA_Coastal2", 
                        "KEN_Sokoke1", "GNB_Cacheu", "MWI_Liwonde", "CIV_Tai", "SOM_Jubba", 
                        "ZAF_DeHoop", "ZAF_Durban", "CIV_Tai", "SWZ_IYSIS", "TZA_Usambara1", 
                        "GIN_Ziama1", "CMR_Mpem", "GIN_Nimba2", "LBR_Nimba1", "SWZ_Lubombo", 
                        "CMR_Cameroon1", "LBR_Nimba1", "COD_Epulu", "GNB_Cantanhez", 
                        "NGA_Gotel", "ZWE_Kanyati", "COD_Epulu", "CIV_Comoe", "SLE_Gola3", 
                        "GIN_Simandou1", "NGA_Edo3", "ETH_Beletta", "MWI_Liwonde", "SLE_Gola1", 
                        "BWA_Xugana", "KEN_Masalani", "CMR_Cameroon3", "ZAF_Kruger3", 
                        "ETH_Godare", "CMR_Mpem", "SLE_Gola3", "GIN_Ziama1", "ZAF_Sudwala", 
                        "CAF_Floris", "CIV_Comoe", "MLI_Bla", "TZA_Usambara1", "SLE_Seli", 
                        "GIN_Simandou2", "ZWE_Sengwa", "LBR_Nimba1", "ZWE_Kanyati", "SLE_Gola3", 
                        "ZWE_Sengwa", "SLE_Seli", "CIV_Tai", "SLE_Seli", "MWI_Mulanje1", 
                        "ZAF_Algeria", "ZAF_Kruger3"), Gen_sp = c("Mops.condylurus", 
                                                                  "Nycteris.thebaica", "Myonycteris.angolensis", "Nycteris.thebaica", 
                                                                  "Myopterus.whitleyi", "Neoromicia.tenuipinnis", "Myotis.tricolor", 
                                                                  "Scotophilus.leucogaster", "Hipposideros.ruber", "Mops.condylurus", 
                                                                  "Miniopterus.natalensis", "Mops.brachypterus", "Mops.condylurus", 
                                                                  "Glauconycteris.humeralis", "Hypsignathus.monstrosus", "Rhinolophus.alcyone", 
                                                                  "Eptesicus.hottentotus", "Taphozous.mauritianus", "Myotis.tricolor", 
                                                                  "Neoromicia.capensis", "Rhinolophus.clivosus", "Miniopterus.natalensis", 
                                                                  "Neoromicia.nana", "Epomops.buettikoferi", "Rousettus.aegyptiacus", 
                                                                  "Scotophilus.livingstonii", "Myonycteris.torquata", "Myotis.bocagii", 
                                                                  "Miniopterus.natalensis", "Megaloglossus.woermanni", "Neoromicia.nana", 
                                                                  "Nycteris.hispida", "Hipposideros.ruber", "Chaerephon.pumilus", 
                                                                  "Rhinolophus.denti", "Nycteris.grandis", "Nanonycteris.veldkampii", 
                                                                  "Kerivoula.lanosa", "Rhinolophus.blasii", "Hipposideros.ruber", 
                                                                  "Hipposideros.marisae", "Rhinolophus.clivosus", "Nycteris.arge", 
                                                                  "Chaerephon.aloysiisabaudiae", "Neoromicia.capensis", "Pipistrellus.rueppellii", 
                                                                  "Neoromicia.guineensis", "Myotis.welwitschii", "Mops.spurrelli", 
                                                                  "Epomophorus.wahlbergi", "Miniopterus.natalensis", "Myotis.tricolor", 
                                                                  "Casinycteris.ophiodon", "Scotophilus.viridis", "Rhinolophus.deckenii", 
                                                                  "Mops.condylurus", "Hipposideros.ruber", "Epomops.buettikoferi", 
                                                                  "Hypsignathus.monstrosus", "Taphozous.mauritianus", "Epomops.franqueti", 
                                                                  "Neoromicia.somalica", "Megaloglossus.woermanni", "Hypsignathus.monstrosus", 
                                                                  "Chaerephon.ansorgei", "Neoromicia.capensis", "Casinycteris.argynnis", 
                                                                  "Nycteris.intermedia", "Myonycteris.leptodon", "Kerivoula.cuprosa", 
                                                                  "Eidolon.helvum", "Myonycteris.torquata", "Neoromicia.nana", 
                                                                  "Hypsignathus.monstrosus", "Chaerephon.pumilus", "Miniopterus.arenarius", 
                                                                  "Myonycteris.angolensis", "Nycticeinops.schlieffeni", "Neoromicia.guineensis", 
                                                                  "Rousettus.aegyptiacus", "Glauconycteris.variegata", "Miniopterus.villiersi", 
                                                                  "Neoromicia.capensis", "Neoromicia.nana", "Hipposideros.ruber", 
                                                                  "Scotophilus.leucogaster", "Scotophilus.andrewreborii", "Mops.nanulus", 
                                                                  "Eidolon.helvum", "Nycteris.thebaica", "Micropteropus.pusillus", 
                                                                  "Mops.condylurus", "Hipposideros.abae", "Neoromicia.capensis", 
                                                                  "Eidolon.helvum", "Macronycteris.gigas", "Hipposideros.jonesi", 
                                                                  "Rhinolophus.fumigatus", "Cistugo.lesueuri", "Scotophilus.dinganii"
                        ), Numbers = c(3L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 
                                       2L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 227L, 
                                       4L, 33L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 29L, 1L, 187L, 2L, 
                                       1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 39L, 2L, 1L, 80L, 5L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 64L, 1L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 5L, 
                                       7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 29L, 31L, 21L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 19L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 53L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 32L
                        ), presence = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                        1)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would structure my code to accomplish this. If you need help incorporating your biodiversity index calculation into this, let me know, but I think this will set you on the right track.

The idea is to loop over each species that occurs within at least three sites, get all unique 3-length sets of those sites with `gtools::combinations()`, and save all of that info to a list that's organized by species name. Then you can access that list, one species at a time, and calculate whatever indices you have in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)
set.seed(5)

# create an empty list with correct names
theta <- list()

# extract the common species
bats3 <- bats %>% count(Gen_sp) %>% filter(n > 3)

# get the species names
bat_names <- unique(bats3$Gen_sp)

for(sp in bat_names){
  # Get unqiue combinations of sites for each species
  sites <- bats[bats$Gen_sp == sp & bats$presence == 1, "Site"]
  combos <- combinations(n = length(sites), r = 3, v = sites, repeats.allowed = FALSE)
  theta[[sp]] <- list(sites_present = sites, combos = combos)

  # Calculate some biodiversity index
  theta[[sp]]["gamma"] <- "some biodiversity index function value"
}

# Get all sets of sites for each species like this
theta[["Hipposideros.ruber"]][["combos"]]

# Get one set of sites like this
theta[["Hipposideros.ruber"]][["combos"]][1,]
```